CORS error when importing micro frontend on different domain
Some of my micro frontends are hosted on a different domain that requires authentication so when my SPA tries to access those they get a redirect which then results in a CORS error.
My browser is already authenticated to the external domain and the server CORS are set up to allow cross-origin requests.
Example of my SPA
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js" as="script">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.7/runtime.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap" />
    
    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
        "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js",
        "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js",
        "rxjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/rxjs/system/es2015/rxjs.min.js",
        "rxjs/operators": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@esm-bundle/rxjs/system/es2015/rxjs-operators.min.js"
      }
    }
    </script>
    

    <!-- Import map URLs are added by WebPack -->
    <script id="mfImports" type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@frontends/mf-local": "/mf-local.js",
        "@frontends/mf-external": "https://my-extarnal.doman.com/mf-external.js",
      }
    }
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/import-map-overrides@2.2.0/dist/import-map-overrides.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/extras/amd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

The import of @frontends/mf-external results in CORS error because of auth redirect. How can I tell single-spa to import the external resource with property XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials=true?
